# How to get the constructor name in Node.js from super class

Tags: javascript, node.js, dkan

I have a "super" module in my Node.js application with a constructor and some prototype functions.

```
var parser = function(options, util, cache, url) {

    this.options        = options;
    this.util           = util;
    this.cache          = cache;
    this.url            = url;
}

parser.prototype.start = function() {
    console.log("I am a default start function");
    console.log(this.constructor.name);
}

module.exports = parser;
```

I have a handful of other modules that inherit from this module. Now, when i invoke the `start` function i would like to get the name of that module's constructor. For some reason this is not working for me.

```
var parser = require('../parser');
var util   = require('util');

var DKAN = function(options, util, cache, url) {

    parser.apply(this,arguments);

}

util.inherits(DKAN, parser);

DKAN.prototype.check = function($) {
    var DKANParser = this;
    if ($('meta[content*="Drupal"]').length !== 0 ) {
        DKANParser.start();
        return true;
    } else return false;
}

module.exports = DKAN;
```

When invoking the `DKANParser.start()` i only get the first `console.log` with "I am a default start function" and cannot get the name of constructor whih is supposed to be DKAN

Comment: Your constructor has no name, `DKAN = function DKAN(...)`

Comment: damn .. i must turn off and sleep now for not seeing this :) thanks a lot

Comment: Use a function declaration: `function DKAN(...) {...}`.